# Interpolate series data index (sec) by adding n new indexes between existing index

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, indexing, interpolation, series

I have some series data that is a product of a [.groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) and [.aggregate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html?highlight=aggregate) functions of pandas. For simplicity i use part of the series as they are much bigger. Also note that the **index interval is semi-irregular**

```
index       T_degC
1590000     94.766390
2870000     94.792032
4150000     94.809170
5430000     94.820314
7990000     94.829617
10550000    94.831792
15670000    94.824710
20790000    94.812653
```

What i would like to achieve is to interpolate the values for index (time in sec) and temperature. From what i have been able to gather, i should re-index to create the "slots" and then interpolate the T_degC values. 
something like (in this case for n = 2):

```
    index       T_degC
    ........
    1590000     94.766390
(new index)     Nan
(new index)     Nan
    2870000     94.792032
(new index)     Nan
(new index)     Nan
    4150000     94.809170
(new index)     Nan
(new index)     Nan
    5430000     94.820314
    .............
```

first and then interpolate and get

```
    index       T_degC
........
    1590000     94.766390
(new index)     (new value)
(new index)     (new value)
    2870000     94.792032
(new index)     (new value)
(new index)     (new value)
    4150000     94.809170
(new index)     (new value)
(new index)     (new value)
    5430000     94.820314
.............
```

So the question boils down to this:
How can i add an n number of new indexes between the original indexes and then interpolate the temperature values? 
A time interval (i.e. every 1000sec) would not be desirable as the original index is semi-irregular.

tried something like this:

```
foo = data.T_degC.reindex(index=np.arange(data.index.min(),data.index.max(), 1000))
```

but it only overwrites the existing index and looses my original values, plus its not really adding n values new indexes between the original ones....

Comment: Have you tried `pandas.resample` instead? Can you provide some random data values to test this?

Comment: Your own solution works for me (Pandas 0.17.1), so I cannot reproduce your problem with loosing original values. You will loose your last value however, since np.arange() excludes the stop value (data.index.max()). You can either just add another step to the stop value, or look into np.linspace() which can handle endpoints better.

Comment: @CoderBC  `pandas.resample` seems interesting although documentation suggest its best used for regular time-series data. My data is none of the two as the index is just a numerical value that represents sec

Comment: @rhkarls my own solution overwrites the values for T_degC therefore nothing left to perform the interpolation with. The linspace is a better option for this indeed but i think the approach overall is not fit for purpose

Comment: @alex-d I understand that, but just saying I cannot reproduce the problem (i.e. I can reindex your dataframe just fine, all values are kept). Could it be a dtype issue with your index?